# SSIS - How to fix error rows before running the package

Tags: csv, ssis

I'm loading an SSIS package to get data from 5 CSV files each has few million rows. I have created a package to read from the CSV one after the other and load into a table. I have corrected all validation errors. But when I ran I found lots of load errors due to wrong and invalid data. I would like to know if there is way to find the error rows in advance, so I can fix them and run the package without any errors, Now I have to run the package again and again which is taking ages. 
I have already tried redirecting the error rows to flat file, but just wondering is there any best practice for such scenarios. Please advise.
 
Thanks

John

Answer (score 0):

You probably want to profile your data and decide what you want to happen in each situation.  If you know the rules in advance, then the fixes can be applied either at source or within SSIS.

You might find it useful to utilise [Microsoft Data Quality Services](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff877917.aspx) and / or the [Data Profiling Task](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb895310.aspx) (if you can stage the raw data in SQL first) to review the data

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, i'll try this